# Typescript Object type does not allow access to properties

Tags: angular, typescript

i am trying to create a variable with Object type and initialised it with a property. but when i try to access that property it shows error 'Property ____ does not exist on type Object'. I had already searched for this and i found there are 3 type object , Object and {}. I can access my properties with {} but not with object and Object.

```
export class customDirective {
    configg:Object={
        qSelector:'.card-text'
    };
    @HostListener('mouseover') onmouseover(){
        var element =this.el.nativeElement.querySelector(this.configg.qSelector);
        this.ren.setElementStyle(element, 'display', 'block');
        this.isHovering = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Access property of object type using **[ ]**

i.e. `this.configg['qSelector']` not `this.configg.qSelector`

```
export class customDirective {
    configg:Object={
        qSelector:'.card-text'
    };
    @HostListener('mouseover') onmouseover(){
        var element =this.el.nativeElement.querySelector(this.configg['qSelector']);
        this.ren.setElementStyle(element, 'display', 'block');
        this.isHovering = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: If this answer is helpful then please approve it.

Answer (score 0):

`Object` is an actual class: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object. It has certain properties defined, and `qSelector` is not one of it.

To define an arbitrary object that can have any properties set without TypeScript complaining, use the `any` type (or leave out the type definition altogether):

```
configg: any = {
    qSelector:'.card-text'
};
```

Comment: And you loose all type checking by doing this. There is no point to use TypeScript when you type everything as `any`.

Comment: Sure. If you want to re-use your object, profit from type checking during compilation, have proper code completion available in your favorite IDE, ..., you should probably type it.